# list.files sometimes adds a slash after the path being searched and sometimes does not add a slash

Tags: r

I am using `list.files` (or `dir`) to recursively list the files in a directory on a Windows 10 machine. When I set `path = "C:/"`, the output has a double `/`. When I set `path = "C:"` the output has no `/` after the drive letter.

```
files_slash <- list.files("C:/", full.names = T, recursive = T, include.dirs = F, no.. = T)
head(files_slash)
[1] "C://$MfeDeepRem/SESSION_COUNT"                                                         
[2] "C://$MfeDeepRem/TERMINATED_SESSIONS/00000001-008e-45fc-8bc2-b49aa3452139/CHANGE_LOG"   
[3] "C://$MfeDeepRem/TERMINATED_SESSIONS/00000001-008e-45fc-8bc2-b49aa3452139/CONFIG_DATA"  
[4] "C://$MfeDeepRem/TERMINATED_SESSIONS/00000001-008e-45fc-8bc2-b49aa3452139/PROCESS_GUIDS"
[5] "C://$MfeDeepRem/TERMINATED_SESSIONS/00000001-01fb-4ff3-9e1f-5c6e94f35645/CHANGE_LOG"   
[6] "C://$MfeDeepRem/TERMINATED_SESSIONS/00000001-01fb-4ff3-9e1f-5c6e94f35645/CONFIG_DATA"  

files_noslash <- dir("C:", full.names = T, recursive = T, include.dirs = F, no.. = T)
head(files_noslash)
[1] "C:$MfeDeepRem/SESSION_COUNT"                                                         
[2] "C:$MfeDeepRem/TERMINATED_SESSIONS/00000001-008e-45fc-8bc2-b49aa3452139/CHANGE_LOG"   
[3] "C:$MfeDeepRem/TERMINATED_SESSIONS/00000001-008e-45fc-8bc2-b49aa3452139/CONFIG_DATA"  
[4] "C:$MfeDeepRem/TERMINATED_SESSIONS/00000001-008e-45fc-8bc2-b49aa3452139/PROCESS_GUIDS"
[5] "C:$MfeDeepRem/TERMINATED_SESSIONS/00000001-01fb-4ff3-9e1f-5c6e94f35645/CHANGE_LOG"   
[6] "C:$MfeDeepRem/TERMINATED_SESSIONS/00000001-01fb-4ff3-9e1f-5c6e94f35645/CONFIG_DATA"
```

In response to a question in the comments, the "C:" version (without the `/`), causes problems, so that is definitely the wrong way to do this:

```
> file.exists("C://$MfeDeepRem/SESSION_COUNT")
[1] TRUE
> file.exists("C:$MfeDeepRem/SESSION_COUNT")
[1] FALSE
```

I can use `sub` to fix the double `//`, but it doesn't seem like this should not happen. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Note, this inconsistency only happens with "C:" (or, I assume, other drive letters). If I give a longer path (e.g. "C:/Users" or "C:/Users/"), a `/` is always appended to the path.

Comment: Regardless of what it shows, does `file.exists("C://$MfeDeepRem/SESSION_COUNT")` or `file.exists("C:$MfeDeepRem/SESSION_COUNT")` return `TRUE`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your paths are fine. Don't worry about the extra forwardslash. just normalize them. This will ensure they all look the same.

ie

```
files_slash <- list.files("C:/", full.names = T, recursive = T, include.dirs = F, no.. = T)
final_files_path <- normalizePath(files_slash)
```

Comment: I modified it to `normalizePath(files_slash, winslash = "/")` because I find this more readable than the double backslash.